# startx crashes with no errors

Tags: debian, xorg, startx, x

I am having a weird problem trying to run startx on my debian desktop. It crashes and dumps me back into the shell, with no indication as to what went wrong (that I can see). It had worked previously, but the problem started after a dist-upgrade, which was interrupted when the screen locked.

System info: debian stretch, AMD threadripper, GTX 1070

Here is the Xorg.0.log

```
[    39.401] 
X.Org X Server 1.19.2
Release Date: 2017-03-02
[    39.402] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    39.402] Build Operating System: Linux 4.9.0-8-amd64 x86_64 Debian
[    39.402] Current Operating System: Linux desk 4.9.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.130-2 (2018-10-27) x86_64
[    39.402] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-4.9.0-8-amd64 root=/dev/mapper/desk--vg-root ro quiet
[    39.402] Build Date: 03 November 2018  03:09:11AM
[    39.402] xorg-server 2:1.19.2-1+deb9u5 (https://www.debian.org/support) 
[    39.403] Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
[    39.403]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    39.403] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    39.404] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Mon Dec 10 22:44:07 2018
[    39.405] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
[    39.405] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    39.407] (==) ServerLayout "Layout0"
[    39.407] (**) |-->Screen "Screen0" (0)
[    39.407] (**) |   |-->Monitor "Monitor0"
[    39.408] (**) |   |-->Device "Device0"
[    39.408] (**) |-->Input Device "Keyboard0"
[    39.408] (**) |-->Input Device "Mouse0"
[    39.408] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    39.408] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    39.408] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[    39.408] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[    39.414] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[    39.414]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    39.414] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[    39.414]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    39.414] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[    39.414]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    39.416] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[    39.416]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    39.416] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[    39.416]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    39.416] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
[    39.416] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    39.416] (WW) Hotplugging is on, devices using drivers 'kbd', 'mouse' or 'vmmouse' will be disabled.
[    39.416] (WW) Disabling Keyboard0
[    39.416] (WW) Disabling Mouse0
[    39.416] (II) Loader magic: 0x556fcd03ae00
[    39.416] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    39.416]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    39.416]    X.Org Video Driver: 23.0
[    39.416]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[    39.416]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[    39.416] (++) using VT number 1

[    39.422] (II) systemd-logind: took control of session /org/freedesktop/login1/session/_31
[    39.422] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[    39.423] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/dri/card0 226:0 fd 11 paused 0
[    39.425] (--) PCI:*(0:65:0:0) 10de:13c2:3842:2978 rev 161, Mem @ 0xec000000/16777216, 0xd0000000/268435456, 0xe0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x0000f000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[    39.425] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    39.428] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/linux/libglx.so
[    39.493] (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    39.493]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    39.493]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[    39.494] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  390.87  Tue Aug 21 16:10:56 PDT 2018
[    39.495] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[    39.495] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nvidia_drv.so
[    39.503] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    39.503]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    39.503]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    39.504] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  390.87  Tue Aug 21 15:44:49 PDT 2018
[    39.504] (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
[    39.505] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 226:0
[    39.506] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[    39.506] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[    39.507] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[    39.508] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    39.508]    compiled for 1.19.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    39.508]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    39.508] (II) Loading sub module "wfb"
[    39.508] (II) LoadModule: "wfb"
[    39.508] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libwfb.so
[    39.510] (II) Module wfb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    39.510]    compiled for 1.19.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    39.510]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    39.510] (II) Loading sub module "ramdac"
[    39.510] (II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
[    39.510] (II) Module "ramdac" already built-in
[    39.513] (**) NVIDIA(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[    39.513] (==) NVIDIA(0): RGB weight 888
[    39.513] (==) NVIDIA(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[    39.513] (==) NVIDIA(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[    39.513] (**) NVIDIA(0): Enabling 2D acceleration
[    40.400] (--) NVIDIA(0): Valid display device(s) on GPU-0 at PCI:65:0:0
[    40.400] (--) NVIDIA(0):     CRT-0
[    40.400] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-0
[    40.400] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-1 (boot)
[    40.400] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-2
[    40.400] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-3
[    40.400] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-4
[    40.401] (II) NVIDIA(0): NVIDIA GPU GeForce GTX 970 (GM204-A) at PCI:65:0:0 (GPU-0)
[    40.401] (--) NVIDIA(0): Memory: 4194304 kBytes
[    40.401] (--) NVIDIA(0): VideoBIOS: 84.04.84.00.71
[    40.401] (II) NVIDIA(0): Detected PCI Express Link width: 16X
[    40.403] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): CRT-0: disconnected
[    40.403] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): CRT-0: 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    40.403] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    40.406] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: disconnected
[    40.406] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: Internal TMDS
[    40.406] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    40.406] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    40.437] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): LG Electronics LG ULTRAWIDE (DFP-1): connected
[    40.437] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): LG Electronics LG ULTRAWIDE (DFP-1): Internal TMDS
[    40.437] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): LG Electronics LG ULTRAWIDE (DFP-1): 600.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    40.437] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    40.437] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DELL U2412M (DFP-2): connected
[    40.437] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DELL U2412M (DFP-2): Internal DisplayPort
[    40.437] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DELL U2412M (DFP-2): 960.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    40.437] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    40.439] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: disconnected
[    40.439] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: Internal TMDS
[    40.439] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    40.439] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    40.439] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: disconnected
[    40.439] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: Internal TMDS
[    40.439] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    40.439] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    40.443] (==) NVIDIA(0): 
[    40.443] (==) NVIDIA(0): No modes were requested; the default mode "nvidia-auto-select"
[    40.443] (==) NVIDIA(0):     will be used as the requested mode.
[    40.443] (==) NVIDIA(0): 
[    40.443] (II) NVIDIA(0): Validated MetaModes:
[    40.443] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "DFP-1:nvidia-auto-select,DFP-2:nvidia-auto-select"
[    40.443] (II) NVIDIA(0): Virtual screen size determined to be 4480 x 1200
[    40.446] (--) NVIDIA(0): DPI set to (97, 97); computed from "UseEdidDpi" X config
[    40.446] (--) NVIDIA(0):     option
[    40.446] (--) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[    40.447] (II) NVIDIA: Using 6144.00 MB of virtual memory for indirect memory
[    40.447] (II) NVIDIA:     access.
[    40.473] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "DFP-1:nvidia-auto-select,DFP-2:nvidia-auto-select"
[    40.537] (==) NVIDIA(0): Disabling shared memory pixmaps
[    40.537] (==) NVIDIA(0): Backing store enabled
[    40.537] (==) NVIDIA(0): Silken mouse enabled
[    40.538] (**) NVIDIA(0): DPMS enabled
[    40.538] (II) Loading sub module "dri2"
[    40.538] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[    40.538] (II) Module "dri2" already built-in
[    40.538] (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[    40.538] (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: nvidia
[    40.538] (--) RandR disabled
[    40.541] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
[    40.542] (II) Initializing extension GLX
[    40.542] (II) Indirect GLX disabled.
[    40.613] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event5)
[    40.613] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    40.613] (II) LoadModule: "libinput"
[    40.613] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/libinput_drv.so
[    40.618] (II) Module libinput: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    40.618]    compiled for 1.19.0, module version = 0.23.0
[    40.618]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[    40.618]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 24.1
[    40.618] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
[    40.619] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event5 13:69 fd 37 paused 0
[    40.619] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[    40.619] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event5"
[    40.619] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    40.619] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event5 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    40.619] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event5 is a keyboard
[    40.619] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input8/event5"
[    40.619] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 6)
[    40.619] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    40.619] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    40.620] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event5 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    40.620] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event5 is a keyboard
[    40.620] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event4)
[    40.620] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    40.620] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
[    40.621] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event4 13:68 fd 40 paused 0
[    40.621] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[    40.621] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event4"
[    40.621] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    40.621] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event4 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    40.621] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event4 is a keyboard
[    40.621] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input7/event4"
[    40.621] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 7)
[    40.621] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    40.621] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    40.622] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event4 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    40.622] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event4 is a keyboard
[    40.622] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Audioengine Audioengine D1 (/dev/input/event0)
[    40.622] (**) Audioengine Audioengine D1: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    40.622] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Audioengine Audioengine D1'
[    40.623] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event0 13:64 fd 41 paused 0
[    40.623] (**) Audioengine Audioengine D1: always reports core events
[    40.623] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event0"
[    40.623] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    40.623] (II) input device 'Audioengine Audioengine D1', /dev/input/event0 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    40.623] (II) input device 'Audioengine Audioengine D1', /dev/input/event0 is a keyboard
[    40.623] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.1/0000:08:00.3/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.2/0003:2912:30C8.0001/input/input3/event0"
[    40.623] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Audioengine Audioengine D1" (type: KEYBOARD, id 8)
[    40.623] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    40.623] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    40.624] (II) input device 'Audioengine Audioengine D1', /dev/input/event0 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    40.624] (II) input device 'Audioengine Audioengine D1', /dev/input/event0 is a keyboard
[    40.624] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HID 04b3:3107 (/dev/input/event1)
[    40.624] (**) HID 04b3:3107: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
[    40.624] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'HID 04b3:3107'
[    40.684] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event1 13:65 fd 42 paused 0
[    40.684] (**) HID 04b3:3107: always reports core events
[    40.684] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event1"
[    40.684] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    40.684] (II) input device 'HID 04b3:3107', /dev/input/event1 is tagged by udev as: Mouse
[    40.684] (II) input device 'HID 04b3:3107', /dev/input/event1 is a pointer caps
[    40.684] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.1/0000:08:00.3/usb3/3-3/3-3.1/3-3.1:1.0/0003:04B3:3107.0003/input/input4/event1"
[    40.684] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "HID 04b3:3107" (type: MOUSE, id 9)
[    40.684] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
[    40.684] (**) HID 04b3:3107: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[    40.684] (**) HID 04b3:3107: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[    40.684] (**) HID 04b3:3107: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[    40.685] (II) input device 'HID 04b3:3107', /dev/input/event1 is tagged by udev as: Mouse
[    40.685] (II) input device 'HID 04b3:3107', /dev/input/event1 is a pointer caps
[    40.685] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HID 04b3:3107 (/dev/input/mouse0)
[    40.685] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    40.685] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    40.685] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Apple Inc. Apple Keyboard (/dev/input/event2)
[    40.685] (**) Apple Inc. Apple Keyboard: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    40.685] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Apple Inc. Apple Keyboard'
[    40.686] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event2 13:66 fd 43 paused 0
[    40.686] (**) Apple Inc. Apple Keyboard: always reports core events
[    40.686] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event2"
[    40.686] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    40.686] (II) input device 'Apple Inc. Apple Keyboard', /dev/input/event2 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    40.686] (II) input device 'Apple Inc. Apple Keyboard', /dev/input/event2 is a keyboard
[    40.686] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.1/0000:08:00.3/usb3/3-3/3-3.2/3-3.2:1.0/0003:05AC:024F.0004/input/input5/event2"
[    40.686] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Apple Inc. Apple Keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 10)
[    40.686] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    40.686] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    40.687] (II) input device 'Apple Inc. Apple Keyboard', /dev/input/event2 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    40.687] (II) input device 'Apple Inc. Apple Keyboard', /dev/input/event2 is a keyboard
[    40.687] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Apple Inc. Apple Keyboard (/dev/input/event3)
[    40.687] (**) Apple Inc. Apple Keyboard: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    40.687] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Apple Inc. Apple Keyboard'
[    40.688] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event3 13:67 fd 44 paused 0
[    40.688] (**) Apple Inc. Apple Keyboard: always reports core events
[    40.688] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event3"
[    40.688] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    40.688] (II) input device 'Apple Inc. Apple Keyboard', /dev/input/event3 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    40.688] (II) input device 'Apple Inc. Apple Keyboard', /dev/input/event3 is a keyboard
[    40.688] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.1/0000:08:00.3/usb3/3-3/3-3.2/3-3.2:1.1/0003:05AC:024F.0005/input/input6/event3"
[    40.688] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Apple Inc. Apple Keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 11)
[    40.688] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    40.688] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    40.688] (II) input device 'Apple Inc. Apple Keyboard', /dev/input/event3 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    40.688] (II) input device 'Apple Inc. Apple Keyboard', /dev/input/event3 is a keyboard
[    40.689] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HD-Audio Generic Front Mic (/dev/input/event7)
[    40.689] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    40.689] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    40.689] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HD-Audio Generic Rear Mic (/dev/input/event8)
[    40.689] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    40.689] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    40.689] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HD-Audio Generic Line (/dev/input/event9)
[    40.689] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    40.689] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    40.689] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HD-Audio Generic Line Out Front (/dev/input/event10)
[    40.689] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    40.689] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    40.689] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HD-Audio Generic Line Out Surround (/dev/input/event11)
[    40.689] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    40.689] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    40.690] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HD-Audio Generic Line Out CLFE (/dev/input/event12)
[    40.690] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    40.690] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    40.690] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HD-Audio Generic Front Headphone (/dev/input/event13)
[    40.690] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    40.690] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    40.690] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event14)
[    40.690] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    40.690] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    40.690] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7 (/dev/input/event15)
[    40.690] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    40.690] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    40.690] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8 (/dev/input/event16)
[    40.691] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    40.691] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    40.691] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=9 (/dev/input/event17)
[    40.691] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    40.691] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    40.691] (II) config/udev: Adding input device PC Speaker (/dev/input/event6)
[    40.691] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    40.691] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    40.694] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DELL U2412M (DFP-2): connected
[    40.694] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DELL U2412M (DFP-2): Internal DisplayPort
[    40.694] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DELL U2412M (DFP-2): 960.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    40.694] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    41.514] (**) Option "fd" "37"
[    41.514] (**) Option "fd" "40"
[    41.514] (**) Option "fd" "41"
[    41.514] (**) Option "fd" "42"
[    41.514] (**) Option "fd" "43"
[    41.514] (**) Option "fd" "44"
[    41.516] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[    41.516] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:67
[    41.540] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[    41.540] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:66
[    41.572] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[    41.572] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:65
[    41.608] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[    41.608] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:64
[    41.632] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[    41.632] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:68
[    41.656] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[    41.656] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:69
[    42.223] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Deleting GPU-0
[    42.225] (II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```

And here is my xorg.conf

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 384.111  (buildd@debian)  Sun Feb 25 23:27:00 UTC 2018


Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Comment: This is over my head, but the first thing I would want to know is what went wrong in the dist-upgrade? Maybe there are some packages with incompatible versions still installed. You ought to be able to finish the dist-upgrade from a virtual console without X if you have not already done so. And do a `sudo apt install -f` after that to make sure anything still broken is either fixed or brought to your attention.

Comment: Nothing went wrong on the OP's side. Also, nothing's wrong with X. It doesn't crash, it stops because it's got nothing left to do. I ran into something simular before I switched to Devuan. From one release to another, Debian dropped kdm. When upgrading, it wasn't replaced by an alternative. Ergo, X seems to crash.

Answer (score 1):

Try starting X11 with startx and no `.xinitrc` and no `.xsession`.

Your `Xorg.conf` looks ok. I had the same problem with a similar setup (Debian Stretch, i8700, Nvidia GTX2070). In my case the problem was in the `.xinitrc`, which contained just one line for `setxkbmap` that I didn't need anyway. After removing `.xinitrc` I was able to start X11 with `startx` without any problems.

Comment: Thank you so much. For me the window manager (dwm) binary path was incorrect. Fixed and worked!